# Linux: Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path 'python'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a problem with VS Code:

```
Linux: Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path 'python'
```

I have tried to change the `settings.json` and `launch.json`files, but it did nothing, I have installed Preview Python, and it is this where this error comes from, but I don't know how to fix it.

When I stay clicked on it:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3"
```

It tells me: `unknown configuration settings: no quick fixes available`

Comment: The error message implies that `/usr/local/bin/python3` isn't actually being used. Make sure it's the correct setting, made in the correct place, actually loaded, &c.

Comment: You probably did not add python to your environment variable path.

Answer (score 1):

I have some checks that you can follow in order to make it work.

1. Check that Python is correctly installed. You can check via :

```bash
    $ python -v
```

2. You can probably update the Python path on VS Code, in the `settings.json` file, and check the value of `"python.pythonPath"`. On Linux, it's commonly `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/local/bin/python3`.
3. Restart VS Code, it can be stupid, but sometimes, it works!  Or just go on the command palette and type `Reload Window` to reload the window thanks to that command.
4. Try installing the Python Extension, in the VS Code extension tab. It can solve your problem, and ensure that you have the latest version.
5. Verify you Launch Configuration. I found this last answer somewhere else, so I just paste here the output :
   Open the `.vscode/launch.json` file and check the `"pythonPath"` property in the launch configuration. It should match the Python executable path you've configured in the settings. If the property is missing or incorrect, update it accordingly.
6. Make sure you have the necessary permissions to access the Python executable and that it's located in the right specified path.

Now, if you followed all this steps, Python should now work on your VS Code window! (I hope this is the case)
If it doesn't work, provide me more details about your configuration.